# 3 Separate Text Alignments on one UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, core-text, nsattributedstring

I have UILabel that I wish to split into 3 columns per say.
I'm looking to have the first range (NSRangeMake(0,5) be kCTLeftAlignment, the second range to have kCTCenterAlignment, and the third to have kCTRightAlignment.

I haven't used CoreText yet, so I was just trying to change the (currently NSTextAlignmentLeft) text alignment to kCTRightAlignment, but I'm getting a crash.

Here is my code so far. The UILabel is displaying properly, works without the attributedText, etc. I'm just looking for some NSAttributedString help.

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)_title {
    titleLabel.text = _title;
    NSMutableAttributedString * attr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_title];

    CTTextAlignment theAlignment = kCTRightTextAlignment;
    CFIndex theNumberOfSettings = 1;
    CTParagraphStyleSetting theSettings[1] = {{ kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(CTTextAlignment), &theAlignment }};
    CTParagraphStyleRef theParagraphRef = CTParagraphStyleCreate(theSettings, theNumberOfSettings);
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)theParagraphRef, (id)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil]; 
    [attr addAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0, _title.length)];

    titleLabel.attributedText = attr;
}
```

And here is the error/crash

```
2013-01-24 13:05:59.928 Expandable[12376:c07] -[__NSCFType lineBreakMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x716f1b0
2013-01-24 13:05:59.929 Expandable[12376:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType lineBreakMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x716f1b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x157c012 0x13a1e7e 0x16074bd 0x156bbbc 0x156b94e 0x33ebea1 0x33eba56 0x446c24 0x4452e9 0x4476a8 0x3394be 0x203a3f 0x20396b 0x115697 0x20383c 0x2039ba 0x2032b6 0x203994 0x1f80e2 0x1f815c 0x1760bc 0x177227 0x1778e2 0x1544afe 0x1544a3d 0x15227c2 0x1521f44 0x1521e1b 0x19f87e3 0x19f8668 0x2e965c 0x209d 0x1fc5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

I have done some searching and research to get this far, but I'm stuck.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not possible for different ranges of one UILabel to have separate alignments. Are you open to using three different UILabels?

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to. It'll probably be more efficient to draw the text with CoreText. It's in a custom tableviewcell.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you create a CTParagraphStyle with `CTParagraphStyleCreate` you must release the paragraph also if you are using ARC.
So after the `[attr addAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0, _title.length)];` you have to call `CFRelease(theParagraphRef);`.

To fix your crash you have to check the existence of the NSMutableParagraphStyle class (available from iOS 6) and use that.

Your code should looks like this:

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)_title {
    titleLabel.text = _title;
    NSMutableAttributedString *attr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_title];

    if ([NSMutableParagraphStyle class]) {
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
        paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

        [attr addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                     value:paragraphStyle
                     range:NSMakeRange(0, _title.length)];
    }
    else {
        CTTextAlignment theAlignment = kCTRightTextAlignment;
        CFIndex theNumberOfSettings = 1;
        CTParagraphStyleSetting theSettings[1] = {{ kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(CTTextAlignment), &theAlignment }};
        CTParagraphStyleRef theParagraphRef = CTParagraphStyleCreate(theSettings, theNumberOfSettings);
        NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge id)theParagraphRef, (id)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
        [attr addAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0, _title.length)];

        CFRelease(theParagraphRef);
    }
    titleLabel.attributedText = attr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using a `UILabel` but it was crashing on this line         `CGSize expectedLabelSize = [headline sizeWithFont:headlineLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:headlineLabel.lineBreakMode];` and my crash was showing about UITextView `[UITextView lineBreakMode]` so i just initialised my `UILabel` before assigning the value and it worked for me. May be it will be helpful for someone else.